# table in jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I want to add the table like layout to my page.
[image]

The data in the cells will come dynamically from functions.

```
$j.each(records, function() {
    $j('<tr></tr>')
    .hide()
    .attr('id',this.Id)
    .append('<td>' + this.PricebookEntryId+'</td> <td>'+this.Description +'</td> <td>'+this.ListPrice+'</td>')
    .appendTo('#productTable')
    .show();
});
```

but this creates a very simple table which does not look like the screenshot above

[image]

and I can not find such layout in docs.Any pointer will be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: How does the appended code looks like?

Comment: How does it look than? What's the difference betweenthe actual output and the desired one?

Comment: Can you post full code here/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Mobile does not contain a table widget, so your table will not be renedered in the JQM UI.

Options:
1. develop needed enhancements yourself (from your screenshot it looks like pure CSS only)
2. try using the [tableview](http://stokkers.mobi/jqm/tableview/demo.html) raw example I did a while ago using JQM listview and a [Responsive Table Pattern by Filament](https://github.com/frequent/RWD-Table-Patterns)
3. use a the dataTabels version I'm working on (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386821/mobile-data-entry-mobile-friendly-datagrid/10439160#10439160)). This will look the same as (2), but you have all the functionalities of [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) available.